# nbconvert --to latex, remove all prompts

Tags: jinja2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I'd like to remove the typical IPython prompts `In [35]:` from the LaTeX produced by `jupyter-nbconvert --to latex`.

Once there was a template, `style_simple.tplx`, that *almost* did what I want but now it has been removed, otoh its companion templates, `style_bw_ipython.tplx` et c. are still distributed but don't work any more with the new nbconvert.

I understand that I have to write an *ad hoc* template in the `jinja2` template language, but both `jinja2` template syntax and its use in `nbconvert` have eluded my understanding, despite the number of attempts I had made.

Given that I cannot write such a template, I'm seeking assistance with the task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two places prompts appear are the `input` and `execute_result` block.

The [default input block](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/4.2.0/nbconvert/templates/latex/style_ipython.tplx#L22):

```
((* block input scoped *))
    ((( add_prompt(cell.source | highlight_code(strip_verbatim=True), cell, 'In ', 'incolor') )))
((* endblock input *))
```

We can replace that with a block that puts highlighted source code on the page directly in a verbatim block, instead of adding prompts:

```
((* block input scoped *))
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
((( cell.source | highlight_code(strip_verbatim=True) )))
\end{Verbatim}
((* endblock input *))
```

For outputs, we can use the fact that an execute_result output is actually the same as a display_data output, only adding prompts. So we can tell our template to display execute_result outputs the same as display_data:

```
((* block execute_result scoped *))
    ((* block display_data scoped *))
        ((( super() )))
    ((* endblock display_data *))
((* endblock execute_result *))
```

Putting it all together in a custom template, extending the default `article` template:

```
% extend the default article template:
((* extends 'article.tplx' *))

% display input without prompts:
((* block input scoped *))
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
((( cell.source | highlight_code(strip_verbatim=True) )))
\end{Verbatim}
((* endblock input *))

% treat execute_result (output with prompt) as display_data (output without prompt)
((* block execute_result scoped *))
    ((* block display_data scoped *))
        ((( super() )))
    ((* endblock display_data *))
((* endblock execute_result *))
```

If we call this file `noprompts.tplx`, then we can use it with:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to latex --template noprompts mynotebook.ipynb
```

Comment: This works nice, but is it possible to keep the grey background of the input block?